# finding memory access violation for a code

Tags: c, debugging, valgrind

I am noob on valgrind. GCC compiler compiler gave me go flag but an online compiler gave me hard time where I need to submit this code. Please help me finding memory access violation for below code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include"railfence.h"
#define RAIL 2

char* getCipher(char plainText[])
{
    int strln;
    int i;
    int j;
    int k = 0;
    char *result;
    char **arr;

    strln = strlen(plainText);
    if (strln == 0 || strln > 20)
        return "-1";

    for ( i=0 ; i < strln ; i++) 
        if (!isupper(plainText[i])) 
            return "-1";

    arr = (char **) malloc ( RAIL*sizeof(char) );

    for ( i=0 ; i < RAIL ; i++)

        arr[i] = (char *) malloc ( strln*sizeof(char) );

    k = 0;
    for ( i = 0 ; i < strln ; i++ )
        for ( j = 0 ; j < 2 ; j++ ) {
            if ( (i+j)&1 )
                arr[j][i] = '.';
            else
                arr[j][i] = plainText[k++];
        }

    result = (char *) malloc (sizeof(char) * strln);
    k=0;
    strln = strlen(*arr);
    for ( i = 0 ; i < RAIL ; i++ ) {
        for ( j = 0 ; j < strln ; j++ )
        if ( arr[i][j] != '.' )
            result[k++] = arr[i][j];

        free(arr[i]);
    }

    free(arr);
    return result;

}
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include"railfence.h"

int main()
{
        //TestCase 1
        {
                printf("\nTestCase 1\n");
                char plainText[]="ABCDEFGH";
                char * cipherText= getCipher(plainText);
                if(cipherText!=NULL)
                printf("%s\n",cipherText);
        }
}
```

Valgrind Log :

```
==31753== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==31753== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==31753== Using Valgrind-3.10.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==31753== Command: ./main
==31753== 

TestCase 1
==31753== Invalid write of size 8
==31753==    at 0x40079F: getCipher (railfence.c:30)
==31753==    by 0x400977: main (main.c:14)
==31753==  Address 0x51fd040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 2 alloc'd
==31753==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==31753==    by 0x40076F: getCipher (railfence.c:26)
==31753==    by 0x400977: main (main.c:14)
==31753== 
==31753== Invalid read of size 8
==31753==    at 0x40080F: getCipher (railfence.c:38)
==31753==    by 0x400977: main (main.c:14)
==31753==  Address 0x51fd040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 2 alloc'd
==31753==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==31753==    by 0x40076F: getCipher (railfence.c:26)
==31753==    by 0x400977: main (main.c:14)
==31753== 
==31753== Invalid read of size 8
==31753==    at 0x4007EB: getCipher (railfence.c:36)
==31753==    by 0x400977: main (main.c:14)
==31753==  Address 0x51fd048 is 6 bytes after a block of size 2 alloc'd
==31753==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==31753==    by 0x40076F: getCipher (railfence.c:26)
==31753==    by 0x400977: main (main.c:14)
==31753== 
==31753== Invalid read of size 8
==31753==    at 0x400869: getCipher (railfence.c:43)
==31753==    by 0x400977: main (main.c:14)
==31753==  Address 0x51fd040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 2 alloc'd
==31753==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==31753==    by 0x40076F: getCipher (railfence.c:26)
==31753==    by 0x400977: main (main.c:14)
==31753== 
==31753== Invalid read of size 1
==31753==    at 0x4C2E0F4: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==31753==    by 0x400873: getCipher (railfence.c:43)
==31753==    by 0x400977: main (main.c:14)
==31753==  Address 0x51fd098 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==31753==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==31753==    by 0x40079E: getCipher (railfence.c:30)
==31753==    by 0x400977: main (main.c:14)
==31753== 
==31753== Invalid read of size 8
==31753==    at 0x4008A0: getCipher (railfence.c:46)
==31753==    by 0x400977: main (main.c:14)
==31753==  Address 0x51fd040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 2 alloc'd
==31753==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==31753==    by 0x40076F: getCipher (railfence.c:26)
==31753==    by 0x400977: main (main.c:14)
==31753== 
==31753== Invalid read of size 8
==31753==    at 0x4008D9: getCipher (railfence.c:47)
==31753==    by 0x400977: main (main.c:14)
==31753==  Address 0x51fd040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 2 alloc'd
==31753==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==31753==    by 0x40076F: getCipher (railfence.c:26)
==31753==    by 0x400977: main (main.c:14)
==31753== 
==31753== Invalid read of size 8
==31753==    at 0x400909: getCipher (railfence.c:49)
==31753==    by 0x400977: main (main.c:14)
==31753==  Address 0x51fd040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 2 alloc'd
==31753==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==31753==    by 0x40076F: getCipher (railfence.c:26)
==31753==    by 0x400977: main (main.c:14)
==31753== 
==31753== Invalid read of size 1
==31753==    at 0x4C2E0F4: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==31753==    by 0x4EA7C7B: puts (ioputs.c:36)
==31753==    by 0x40098E: main (main.c:16)
==31753==  Address 0x51fd138 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==31753==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==31753==    by 0x400859: getCipher (railfence.c:41)
==31753==    by 0x400977: main (main.c:14)
==31753== 
ACEGBDFH
==31753== 
==31753== HEAP SUMMARY:
==31753==     in use at exit: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
==31753==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 3 frees, 26 bytes allocated
==31753== 
==31753== LEAK SUMMARY:
==31753==    definitely lost: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
==31753==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31753==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31753==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31753==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31753== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==31753== 
==31753== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==31753== ERROR SUMMARY: 47 errors from 9 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: One of the problems is probably here : `arr = (char **) malloc ( RAIL*sizeof(char) );`

Comment: Yeah @DanielKamilKozar, Valgrind is reporting the same line, but I am clueless what is wrong there?

Comment: Do notice the argument of `malloc`.

Comment: Thanks those who voted down :)

Comment: Don't feel bad : just ask better questions next time.

Comment: sometime u can't see a silly mistake. Please if you can suggest me better/right place to ask for peer review...Thanks @DanielKamilKozar for helping on this poor question :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line of code

```
arr = (char **) malloc ( RAIL*sizeof(char) );
```

with this

```
arr = (char **) malloc ( RAIL*sizeof(char*) );
```